# How to change snooze times in Gmail’s new (2018) web interface?

Tags: gmail

I know you can customize the snooze times by using the Inbox by Gmail app, but what is the way to do this directly in Gmail’s web interface?

Comment: Apparently, you can't. Hopefully Google will address this before the pull the plug on Inbox.